# type of reduction does not change under unramified extension

Tags: elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, local-field

Let $K$ be a local field, and $E/K$ be an elliptic curve over $K$.

Let $K'/K$ be unramified extension, then , the reduction type of $E/K'$ is the same as $E/K$.

My proof. Let $E$ be minimal weierstrass equation.Let Discriminant of $E/K$ be $Δ∈R$. Because $K'/K$ is unramified, ramified index is $1$, so,
$v'(Δ)＝v(Δ)/1＝v(Δ)$ and $v'(c_4)＝v(c_4)$.

Reduction type is only determined by v(Δ) and v(c_4), so reduction type over $K$ and $K'$ are the same. *Q.E.D*

But Silverman's book 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves' reads more discussion and proof can be handled only when charactelistic of residue field is not $2,3$.

But My proof seems holds true even when character is $2$ or $3$.

Is my proof correct ? Where am I missing ?

Comment: What procedure are you using to decide the reduction type? I’m looking up Tate’s algorithm and while the gist of your idea seems true, there seems to be a lot more cases to consider.

Comment: Could you tell what kind of case I'm missing? If minimal weierstrass equation is given, reduction type is determined only by sgn of $v(Δ)$ and $v(c_4)$., Silverman's p196, prop5.1, so I only need to prove v(Δ)＝v'(Δ).

Comment: I was looking Tate’s algorithm up on Wikipedia. Anyway, I think the only subtlety is that the proposition you’re quoting only works for a *minimal* model, and it’s perhaps not obvious that the elliptic curve cannot have a better model in a field extension.

Comment: You mean, minimality of weierstrass equation does not hold under the extension of the field , and this is the only ambiguous point ?

Comment: Yes, that’s about the only issue I’m seeing.

Comment: Thank you for helping me !